# Python Function: Allow function to take list as argument and return results as list

Tags: python, list, function, pycharm

I would like to be able to input a list into this function and have it return a list as the results.

```
def counter(num):
    count = 0
    while num != 0:
        if num % 2 == 0:
             num /= 2
        else:
            num -= 1
        count += 1
    return count
```

Right now I can only put in one number at a time, is there anyway to put in a list and have it return a list?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? Why should it return a list?

Comment: It might be cleaner to make another function, e.g. `counter_list`, that takes and returns a list and calls `counter` internally.

Comment: If you want to apply this function onto elements of a list maybe using python map() function i.e. this way: ```python counter_list = map(counter, num_list)```

Answer (score 2):

with one of many ways, you can make a inner function inside this function doing same thing for as this function does, and then do function call to inner function to get the values for the list of numbers

```
def counter(nums: list):
    def _counter(num: int):
        count = 0
        while num != 0:
            if num % 2 == 0:
                num /= 2
            else:
                num -= 1
            count += 1
        return count
    return [_counter(num) for num in nums]
```

Answer (score 1):

The transformation of a function that operates on single numbers (aka "scalars") to one that can operate on arrays of inputs is often called "vectorizing" a function. This is supported out-of-the-box in numpy using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def counter(num):
    count = 0
    while num != 0:
        if num % 2 == 0:
             num /= 2
        else:
            num -= 1
        count += 1
    return count
```

You can then use `counter` as

```
>>> counter([0, 4, 16, 64])
array([0, 3, 5, 7])

>>> counter([0,4,16,64]).tolist()
[0, 3, 5, 7]

>>> counter(64).item()
7
```

Do note that this involves converting between lists and numpy arrays, as well as loops executed in Python (as opposed to in C), so it's not necessarily any more performant than doing the "vectorization" yourself in Python (e.g. with a list comprehension).